# Dini's theorem and strictly convex function

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly convex function which is $C^2$, non-negative and such that $F(0,0)=0$.

1). Prove that the equation $F(x,y)=F(0,1)$ implicitly defines a function $y=\phi(x)$ in $C^2$ for $x$ around $0$ such that $\phi(0)=1$;

2). Prove that $\phi''(0)\leq 0$.

I have proved the first point by using the Dini's theorem but I can't solve the second point by using the fact that $\phi'(x)=-\frac{F_x(x,\phi(x))}{F_y(x,\phi(x))}$.

Comment: When the curve passes  through $(0,0) ,(0,1), $ then $ y^{\prime \prime} \ \leq  0 $

Comment: Note that $F(x,\phi(x)) = 0$. Take the second derivative relative to $x$ of both sides.

Comment: @Narasimham $\phi(0)=1$ so $\phi(x)$ doesn't pass through $(0,0)$

Comment: @WillieWong It leads exactly to derivate $\phi'(x)=-\frac{F_x(x,\phi(x)}{F_y(x,\phi(x)}$ and then, if I am right, $\phi''(0)F_y(0,1)=-F_{xx}(0,1)-2F_{xy}(0,1)\phi'(0)-F_{yy}(0,1)(\phi'(0))^2$ where I know that $F_y(0,1)>0$...but it seems to be still useless...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$F(x,\phi(x))=F(0,1)$$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$:

$$F_x+F_y\phi'=0$$

Differentiate again

$$F_{xx}+F_{xy}\phi'+(F_{yx}+F_{yy}\phi')\phi'+F_y\phi''=0$$

or

$$-F_y\phi''=F_{xx}+2F_{xy}\phi'+F_{yy}(\phi')^2.$$

Substitute for $\phi'$:

$$-F_y\phi''=F_{xx}-2F_{xy}\frac{F_x}{F_y}+F_{yy}\frac{F_x^2}{F_y^2}.$$

Simplify

$$-F_y^3\phi''=F_y^2F_{xx}+F_x^2F_{yy}-2F_xF_yF_{xy}$$

If $F_{xy}(0,1)=0$, then  we get the desired result because convexity of $F$ implies $F_{xx}\geq 0$ and $F_{yy}\geq 0$. So suppose $F_{xy}(0,1)\neq 0$.
Now by convexity of $F$ we know:

$$F_{xx}F_{yy}\geq F_{xy}^2(>0)\iff  F_{yy}\geq \frac{F_{xy}^2}{F_{xx}}$$

Thus

$$-F_y^3\phi''\geq F_y^2F_{xx}+F_x^2\frac{F_{xy}^2}{F_{xx}}-2F_xF_yF_{xy}$$

or, simplifying,

$$-F_y^3\phi''\geq \frac{1}{F_{xx}}[F_y^2F_{xx}^2+F_x^2F_{xy}^2-2F_xF_yF_{xx}F_{xy}]=\frac{1}{F_{xx}}(F_yF_{xx}-F_xF_{xy})^2.$$

Since $F_{xx}(0,1)>0$ by convexity of $F$, the right hand side is nonnegative. Also $F_y(0,1)$ is positive because $F(0,1)>0=F(0,0)$ (if not $F$ would not be strictly convex). The result follows.